# jQuery Conditional Statement Ignored

Tags: jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm building a simple Pick-Up-Jacks game using jQuery, and there is a conditional statement in the `jackPick` function which is just ignored whether it evaluates to true or not.

Any reason why this should happen? Code below:

```
$(function(){

$("#button").click(function(){
    $("#something").animate({marginTop:"+=400px"}, 1200, comeBack());
    $("#something2").animate({marginTop:"+=400px"}, 2500);
    $("#something3").animate({marginTop:"+=400px"}, 3000);
});

function comeBack(){
    $("#something").animate({marginTop:"-=400px"}, 1200);
    $("#something2").animate({marginTop:"-=400px"}, 2500);
    $("#something3").animate({marginTop:"-=400px"}, 3000);
}

var i = 1;
function jackPick(bubble){
    var mt = $(bubble).css("margin-top"); 
        $(bubble).click(function(){
            if (mt != "400px"){
                $("p").html("<p>" +i+ "</p>");
                $(bubble).css({display:"none"});
                i++;
            }
        });
}

jackPick("#something");
jackPick("#something2");
jackPick("#something3");
```

});

Comment: How do you know it is ignored?

Comment: Try putting a `console.log(mt)` in the click event. Check your console to see what the value is. Is it `400px`?

Comment: The result of the if statement still runs whether I click a bubble while in motion or at rest (at 400px). @Gohn67 - didn't think of that thanks!

Comment: It is indeed `400px`, even during the animation when the value is clearly changing in the source code.